# Js function returns undefined even if returned value is valid

Tags: javascript

My function returns `undefined` even if returned value is valid.

```
console.log(getNotParsedArticle());

function getNotParsedArticle() {
    db.all('SELECT article_link FROM helpdb WHERE done = 0 LIMIT 1', (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err.message);
            return null;
        }
        console.log("Got not parsed article: " + result[0].article_link);
        return result[0].article_link;
    });
}
```

Console output:

```
undefined
Got not parsed article: /article/c/basic-medicine
```

I tried add async to function and call it with await, same results.

`db = new sqlite3.Database`

Comment: you don't return anything from the top level of `getNotParsedArticle` - also, await is only relevant to functions that return a Promise

Comment: To make things easier sqlite is a wrapper for sqlite3 that has the functions already wrapped into promises -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getNotParsedArticle` function does not return the value obtained from the database. You can modify your function to use a `promise` to handle the asynchronous operation and return a promise that resolves with the value obtained from the database.

```
function getNotParsedArticle() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.all('SELECT article_link FROM helpdb WHERE done = 0 LIMIT 1', (err, result) => {
            if(err){
                console.log(err.message);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Got not parsed article: " + result[0].article_link);
                resolve(result[0].article_link);
            }
        });
    });
}


getNotParsedArticle()
    .then(articleLink => {
        console.log(articleLink); 
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error occurred:", error);
    });
```